# How to use api property in config of store proxy - the CRUD Methods

Tags: extjs

Can anyone tell me where should we write the create/update etc snippet of codes. I am writing it under the api property of proxy. How to verify the output. Please guide me on how to use store api.

I'm into testing, so please be more clear in making me understand and usage of the functionality

Answer (score 16):

The config itself is [**described here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-api) in the docs. But it sounds like you have the syntax correct.

The first thing you should know is that this config only applies to proxies which extend `Ext.data.proxy.Server`. Read the "Types of Proxy" section [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy).

By defining different URLs in this config you are simply telling the store *where* to send the ajax request to perform the different CRUD actions on your server side.

For example, a call to `store.load()` will send the ajax request to the `api.read` URL, it is up to you to make sure this URL returns the data properly.

An `Ext.data.Store` internally keeps track of the other actions performed on "dirty" records (created, updated or destroyed). Based on this it will send an ajax request to the appropriate `api` config URL. Or if you performed different types of actions e.g. created and deleted records it will send more than one ajax request (one to each URL) along with the data about the records you created or deleted.

Here's some example code to illustrate this (which you could also use for testing if you fill in your own URLs and `data.model`). The example uses the default reader/writer which sends data to the server as JSON (there are configs in the proxy to specify a different format).

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'MyApp.model.SomeModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        // without api defined ALL ajax calls will use the 'url' config
        url: '/some/url',
        api: {
            create: '/some/url/to/insert/records/in/db',
            read: '/some/url/to/select/records/from/db',
            update: '/some/url/to/update/records/in/db',
            destroy: '/some/url/to/delete/records/in/db'
        }
    }
}

// this calls the api.read URL
myStore.load(); 

// assuming we now have records, this will delete the first record 
// on the client side (it will error if there are not records)
myStore.remove(myStore.first());

// the store knows we deleted a record so this will call the api.destroy URL
myStore.sync();

// this updates the first record on the client side
myStore.first().set('some_field_name', 'a string value');

// now we are creating a record on the client side
myStore.add(Ext.create('MyApp.model.SomeModel'));

// the store knows we updated AND created a record so this will call the
// api.update URL AND the api.create URL
myStore.sync();
```

Two other useful tidbits of information about this:

1. There is a proxy config called `batchActions` [**described here in
   the docs**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy-cfg-batchActions). It is `true` by default, which means that all CRUD
   actions of a certain type are grouped into an array when you send
   the request to the database. E.g. if you deleted 4 records, your
   `api.destroy` URL will not receive 4 ajax requests, it will receive 1
   ajax request with an array of 4 records. This helps cut down on the
   network traffic as long as you configure your URL to handle an
   array. You can set this config to `false` and the store will send 4
   requests to the `api.destroy` URL instead. You can also set the
   writer's `allowSingle` config ([**described here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-allowSingle)) to ensure
   that all requests are sent as an array even if there is only one
   record (that way you can set up your server side code to always
   handle an array).
2. `Ext.data.Store` is set-up to handle a callback for create and
       update actions, you just have to make sure your URL sends one back.
       When you call `myStore.sync()` the store will automatically replace
       the record on the client side with the one you send in your
       callback. This is useful for created records because you can send
       back the correct database ID with the created record and have it
       available on the client side, later if the user wants to edit or
       delete the record you have the correct database ID to work with. You
       can also do other processing on the server side and send back other
       data as well so that you have a complete record (e.g. I sometimes
       send back the create user ID and create time as well).